# Can .gltf files read mixRGB nodes in material setup?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, export, gltf

I am trying to export a model that has a material that is made of layered image textures and combined using mixRGB nodes. Here is what the setup looks like: [How do I eliminate the white outline on my layered textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/217862/how-do-i-eliminate-the-white-outline-on-my-layered-textures)

Does anyone know how to export as a .gltf so all of my colors and images show up? Currently I am just getting a black model. I have gone through the gltf 2.0 blender page and tried to follow those parameters but I can't seem to get it right. It seems like .gltf doesn't register/translate the mixRGB nodes??

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541

Comment: @Julia, the glTF format describes a number of PBR parameters (base color, metallic, roughness, etc), but each one can only be a texture or a solid color.  It can't include mix nodes or other Blender-material-specific things.  Merge the images together into a single, final texturemap, and attach that to the base color input.